# How to include jsp with dynamic value on ajax servlet call

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page in which their is header, left and right panel, header and left panel is static. 
Left panel is having href, if we click on link a new page will be loaded in right panel. I want to achieve this task using Jquery Ajax without refreshing whole page.

Now my query is on click of link/button using jquery ajax I call servlet and I from servlet I want to set jsp dynamic values and then load the same in right panel with updated values.

I tried setting the values but I am getting null. Can you please assist me in setting dynamic values in jsp.

Below is my sample code on click of button I want to include hello.jsp with dynamic variable "message" if I succeed here I can solve my above problem.

index.jsp

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JQuery AJAX Testing</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : "AjaxServlet",

            success : function(responseText) {

                $('#message').load("jsp/hello.jsp");
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }

        });
    });


});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="ajaxtest">
<h2>AJAX Testing using JQuery</h2>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
<button>Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

AjaxServlet code:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Servlet post method is called");

    // I want to set this value in hello.jsp
    request.setAttribute("message", "I am from request get attribute");
    response.getWriter().write("This is reply from servlet");

}
```

hello.jsp

```
<h1>Hello this page is include from index JSP</h1>
<%=request.getAttribute("message")%>
```

I want to set message in hello.jsp from servlet on load from JQuery

Pise

Comment: Why are you making two Ajax calls to fetch data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is, get the request param "message" on success not the "jsp/hello.jsp" and then return the request params to the template but not the entire jsp file.

I don't think can load a jsp file like that and have interpreted correctly, plus load() will load the file via a second ajax request and will never return anything to the template via the first request.

try:

```
success : function(responseText) {
        $('#message').html(responseText);
    }
```

Also look at this Q/A on stack to understand the principle of ajax return value:
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I know a way were in we can write whole html content in response.writer and the same I can get in responseText but instead I don't want to write any think in class and want to include jsp just by setting variable values in request.setAttribute.

Comment: Ok check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Comment: I got the point of using JSONObject but my aim is not to make some changes in current jsp but to load a new jsp.

Comment: Please check http://www.tagindex.net/html/frame/example_t04.html   this is done using frame but I want to go with ajax. I want when user clicks on left panel, right panel changes. I will call servlet from left panel and servlet will forward page to some.jsp and same should be displayed in right panel without refreshing left panel.

Comment: please read up on ajax. what you are trying to do is not going to work with ajax.